# How to set custom duration for a holding event in UWP?

Tags: wpf, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm looking for a way to set custom a holding duration for my long-press gesture.

I've reviewed Windows.UI.Input.GestureRecognizer and there is no such option.

I was wondering is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering is it possible at all?

No, you cannot specify the duration of a holding action in your app.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

> The exact timing of what the system interprets as a holding action is adjustable by users through system settings.